# What is the difference between GenerateSW and InjectManifest options available in vue ui pwd config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am using @vue/cli to scaffold vue project. I run vue ui to launch vue UI and now configuring different options available there.

[image]

Under Configuration -> PWA I see above options. What is the meaning of these two options? When one is better over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#which_plugin_to_use).

As per the documentation, `generateSW` should be used for basic requirements as it is simplest to use. When you need/want more control over your service worker and have more complex needs in terms of routing or you want to use your service worker with other API's (e.g. Web Push), you should use `injectManifest` option.